# vb.net MVC - Empty model when form is submitted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok so tearing my hear out as a newbie MVC dev trying to get simply forms submitted on my new MVC site. But when they submit the model shows as empty.

Simple contact us page with name, email and message fields

Here's the simple contact.vbhtml - Has a model type of:

@ModelType Page_ContactUs

form markup

```
    @Using Html.BeginForm("Contact", "AboutUsController", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "contfrm"})
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)
    Html.EnableClientValidation()
    @<div Class="form-group">
    <span Class="input-icon">
        <i Class="material-icons">person</i>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.ContactUs.Name, New With {.class = "form-control", .required = "required", .placeholder = "Enter your Full Name"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ContactUs.Name, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
    </span>
    </div>
    @<div Class="form-group">
    <span Class="input-icon">
        <i Class="material-icons">mail_outline</i>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.ContactUs.Email, New With {.class = "form-control", .[type] = "email", .required = "required", .placeholder = "Enter your Email"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ContactUs.Email, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
    </span>
    </div>
    @<div Class="form-group">
    <span Class="input-icon">
        <i Class="material-icons">comment</i>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(Function(model) model.ContactUs.Enquiry, New With {.class = "form-control", .rows = "5", .required = "required", .placeholder = "Enter your Enquiry", .onchange = "RemoveSpace(this)"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ContactUs.Enquiry, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
    </span>
    </div>
    @<Button type="submit" Class="btn btn-primary">Send</Button>
End Using
```

The page_contactus model looks like this:

```
Public Class Page_ContactUs
    Public ContactUs As Contactus
    Public Content As clsContent
    Public Signup As Signup
End Class
```

My Contact Us model looks like this:

```
Public Class Contactus
    Private _Name As String
    Private _Email As String
    Private _Enquiry As String
    Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Name = value
    End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Email() As String
    Get
        Return _Email
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Email = value
    End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Enquiry() As String
    Get
        Return _Enquiry
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Enquiry = value
    End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And my Contact us controller has this as the http post action, but when it gets here the model is empty

```
<HttpPost()>
<AllowAnonymous()>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
<ActionName("contact")>
Function Contact(Model As Page_ContactUs) As ActionResult


End Function
```

What am I doing wrong?
Cant believe forms are so complicated in MVC, thought this was supposed to make things easier not harder - coming form a web forms background :-(

What have I missed please?

This is still an issue have another page with same problem AGAIN

top of the page has:

@ModelType Page_ReturnItems

form looks like this

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("CompleteReturn", "Account", FormMethod.Post, New With {.class = "form-style-1", .id = "retrnfrm"})
@<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkTerms" name="chkTerms" />&nbsp;I have read, understand And agree To our <a href="/about-us/returns/" target="_blank"><b>Returns Terms &amp; Conditions</b></a><br />
</div>
@<button type="submit" id="buttretitm" Class="btn btn-success" title="Submit Return">Create Return</button>
```

End Using

and it renders like this:

```
<form action="" class="form-style-1" id="retrnfrm" method="post">                            <div>
```

I have read, understand And agree To our **Returns Terms & Conditions**

Create Return

And then in the Account Controller shows this:

```
<HttpPost()>
```

<AllowAnonymous()>
<ActionName("CompleteReturn")>
Function CompleteReturn(Model As Page_ReturnItems) As ActionResult
Try
If ModelState.IsValid Then
Dim PageValidated As Boolean = True
Else
ViewData("ErrorMessage") = "Please enter required fields and try again."
End If
Catch ex As Exception
Logger.LogError(ex)
End Try
End Function

Comment: You might find using a EditorFor templates useful as a way to point to another partial that would contain the bindings for child properties, such as Contactus. -> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contactus)

Comment: Have you imported the correct "Model" inside your " contact.vbhtml" page? (@model YOUR_Model)

Comment: yes correct model

Comment: Is your  @Using Html.BeginForm() inside a <body> tag?